# "using namespace <blank>" within the source for the library <blank>

Tags: c++, libraries

I'm newish to C++, and I'm trying to write a library. I am using a custom namespace for the library, `glz`, as this seems like good practice to avoid conflicts with other libraries. The only problem is the library files end up cluttered with the namespace, especially because I have a bunch of types I've defined. For example I end up with function definitions like,

```
void glz::find_equilibrium(const glz::Grids &grids, const glz::vec_t &F, glz::Consts consts, double beta, glz::point_t gamma, glz::EgVec_t &f, glz::vec_t &rho, glz::vec_t &phi)
```

I would really like to use something like `using namespace glz` within the `.cpp` within the library files. I know this is generally frowned upon, but this seems like a special case where it might be a good idea.

Will this end up messing with the namespace of the library users?

Is there a better way to deal with this?

Comment: No. Everything that is in your cpp is not your public interface, so you can do whatever black-macro-magic you want. Also, you could put your code inside `namespace glz {}`, which would have the same effect.

Comment: `using namespace` is frowned upon when it's in headers (or often if the namespace is `std`). Nothing wrong with using it in .cpp files for your own namespace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Will [using namespace glz within the .cpp] end up messing with the namespace of the library users?

No, there will not be problems for the library users.

But, there can be problems for the library developer / maintainer (i.e. presumably you). The problems are less frequent compared to using namespace in the header.

> Is there a better way to deal with this?

You can simply define the functions within the namespace. That way you can use unqualified names:

```
namespace glz {

void
find_equilibrium(
    const Grids &grids,
    const vec_t &F,
    Consts consts,
    double beta,
    point_t gamma,
    EgVec_t &f,
    vec_t &rho,
    vec_t &phi)
```

Comment: I would like to add that I tried `using namespace glz` in my `.cpp` files and `namespace glz` in the headers an I ended up with a strange function name overloading error (it seemed like the header and the source were overloading the same exact function definition) that disappeared when I just used `namespace glz` in all the files. This seems like the best practice.

Comment: @Alex Problems like that are indeed what I refer to in my second paragraph.